# tesseract can not process *.bmp files

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, tesseract-ocr, bmp

Tesseract can not process *.bmp files. It gives this error.

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v4.00.00alpha with Leptonica
Error in pixReadMemBmp: size incommensurate with image data
Error in pixReadStream: bmp: no pix returned
Error in pixRead: pix not read
Error during processing.
```

tesseract -v

```
tesseract 4.00.00alpha
 leptonica-1.74.4
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.4.2) : libpng 1.2.54 : libtiff 4.0.6 : zlib 1.2.8 : libwebp 0.4.4 : libopenjp2 2.1.0

 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE
```

stable version

```
tesseract 4.0.0
 leptonica-1.75.3
  libgif 5.1.4 : libjpeg 8d (libjpeg-turbo 1.5.2) : libpng 1.6.34 : libtiff 4.0.9 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 0.6.1 : libopenjp2 2.3.0

 Found AVX2
 Found AVX
 Found SSE


Error in pixRemoveColormap: pixs must be {1,2,4,8} bpp
Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
Error in pixGetDepth: pix not defined
Error in pixGetWpl: pix not defined
Error in pixGetYRes: pix not defined
Error in pixClone: pixs not defined
Please call SetImage before attempting recognition.
Error during processing.
```

ubuntu

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Why are you running an alpha version instead of the stable 4.0.0 release?

Comment: the result of alpha release was much better than stable release.

Comment: Stable version also faces error on bmp files.

Comment: So either you have a broken bitmap or you have found a bug (which you should report). Either way we can't help you.

Comment: i think bitmap is not broken. Because i tried many files.

Answer (score 0):

So  convert the bmps to {preferably) tiff if you want to use tesseract on the results.

```
for a in *.bmp; do
  convert $a ${a%.*}.tiff
done
```

For which you need ImageMagick (convert) and bash for the code